# How to get class name from package name in android?

Tags: android, class-names

I want to make a list of both installed and system applications separately.Below is my code

```
List<ApplicationInfo> appList = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(0);
if(appList != null && !appList.isEmpty()){
        for (ApplicationInfo appInfo : appList) {
        Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(appInfo.packageName);
        if(intent != null){
            ComponentName componentName = intent.getComponent();
            if((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1) {
                //It is a system app
            }else{
                //It is an installed app.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to launch each app on click of listview.But the **componentName .getClassName()** shows as "**com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity**" for some applications like Contacts,Map etc....How can i get exact class name of such type of applications.I could not use **ResolveInfo** because it is difficult to categorize applications.

How to get exact class  name of applications using package name ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I ran your sample code on a Galaxy Nexus running 4.2.2, and I didn't get any installed applications showing as ResolverActivity.  Can you give us a little more background?  What are you running this on?  Maybe this isn't a direct path to your answer...but you've got me curious why you're seeing ResolverActivity and I'm not.

Comment: I used Galaxy Tab 2.2

Answer (score -1):

You can ask the packageManager:

```
CharSequence label = "";
for (ApplicationInfo appInfo : appList)    
    label = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(appInfo);
```

Comment: packageManager.getApplicationLabel() returns name of the application.I want to obtain class name